# Usability in Mobile Learning

Tags: usability, mobile, user-research, user-centered-design, learning

I am making a research about interfaces and usability of mobile apps for learning idioms (duolingo, babel, vox, etc).

The research has a objective to gather aspects, such as: *efficiency, learnability and motivations*. In this moment of the research, I decide for three main methods: **usability tests, design probes (diary of study) and interviews**.

I just wondering if someone know about similar case, research or have some tips about other methods/techniques for the pre-tests with users.

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about conducting a survey as well?

It can be very useful to do it before interviews, because you will be able to reach more people and gather more data. People will provide more honest feedback since there is no pressure and less stress. This data will give you a base for your interviews. Since you already will have some information, in your interviews you can dive deeper, and fill all gaps that you have after survey. Also, in the survey you can ask people if they would be interested in a phone/skype/in person interview.

Here is one of the survey tool http://www.typeform.com/

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your comment!
I will do surveys to select participants for the tests. 
Maybe after the interviews with teachers specialists in foreign language, because I need users with different levels of skills in learning foreign idiom and technology.
The typeform is pretty good for this. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I saw a  research on how to use users feedbacks (i.e. comments) in appstore/googleplay as a starting point for usability studies. This was presented in IEEE requirements engineering conference. Will post the link here if I find the paper.